# Enable the rightside categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6yJK.png)In Wordpress, I have created categorie name under post, but after selecting add new post created categories name are not displaying as shown in attached image.
Whether i need to give permission? Please suggest me.
Please refer the attached image , and give solution

Comment: can't see the attached image?

Comment: Now i have attached image, Please check

Comment: In the top right corner of the screen (when you're inside the new post) you have screen options - http://joxi.ru/vAWzE4qt1z76x2  have you checked the categories ?

Comment: I had already searched, but category option is not present

Answer (score 0):

**Put Code Function.php File....**

```
function your_function_name() {
 add_theme_support('post-formats', array(    
   'video', 'aside', 'gallery'
 ));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'your_function_name' );
```

**more information...**

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/post-formats/

Comment: i have tried this code, but its not affecting anywhere

Comment: Please One Time Your Theme Deactive And Again Active Because ( add_action ) Use For After Theme Setup.